# Unrecognized option "csrf_token_generator" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login"

Tags: php, symfony

When I finished creating the `fosuserbundle`, I typed this command to update my database schema:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

And received this error:

> InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 309:
>   Unrecognized option "csrf_token_generator" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login"

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just have to edit my config.yml file ,exactly in the firewall config:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:

```
csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
```

or try to enable

```
framework:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled:  true
```

in your config.yml file